# Do Companies like Microsoft sue users for unpaid online services bills?

Tags: online, bills

Let's say that I have subscribed for a monthly paid services using my credit card, and when the time of paying come the amount that I have as a credit doesn't cover that bill, and after months I couldn't cover the amount to pay for that subscription.

Do Companies like Microsoft or Google or other online services provider sue users for unpaid online services bills?

And what if that user was from another country, outside the US?

Comment: Are you asking the business question "do ISP's usually require payment in advance, or arrears?"

Comment: Generally they don't sue (at least in the US). What they do instead is sell the debt to debt collectors who *might* choose to sue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Large companies are not usually going to take a small case to court; the amount they could recover would be far less than assigning a corporate attorney or hiring an attorney local to the customer to file to collect the debt.

But large companies often assign or sell the debt to a collection agency; such companies specialize in debt collection and lawsuits against those who owe money for services. Collection agencies could pursue people to other countries, depending on local and national laws, or hire or sell the debt to a collection agency in that country.